# Color change in guppy

Tags: health, aquarium, fish, water-parameters

My guppy looked pretty healthy and shiny just three days ago:

[image]

And yesterday... it just darkened. The scale pattern just got so dark all of a sudden. Should I be worried?

And this is today:

[image][image]

Comment: What do you do to clean the water in your tank? What was the result of the last water test?

Comment: How big is the water tank (how many liters or gallons of water)? Did you cycle the tank before you put the fish in or did you get the tank complete with (old!) water and fish from the store? Do you have a water testing kit or can the pet store do a water test for you? My first instinct is that your fish is stressed because its living conditions aren't good. There's probably ammonia in the water, which is poisoning your fish.

Comment: Please answer the questions. We can only guess, if we do not get more information and guessing is not approved on this sites. If you can not provide more information you question will be closed soon :(